# restrict mysql access on xampp server

Tags: php, mysql, xampp

I am installing xampp on a system to be sent to a client with a PHP script that connects to mysql. But I want to restrict access to mysql and phpmyadmin, so the user can't access it in any way through the command line or browser unless it's their php script. Can I do this using user permissions and a root password that only I know?

Thanks!

Comment: Open phpmyadmin - go to users - you will get list of users and their privileges. You can edit and change credentials as well as privileges

Comment: There's no such thing as what you want. When your script connects to mysql, it's purely emulating the same way any client would. You can limit a user to only login from certain IPs or etc, but the command line would still be accessible from the web server you're connecting from.

Comment: Your question is unclear. If they wanna use the database, then how are you planning to allow it?

Answer (score 0):

Basically no normal users will know or wants to enter your database.unless they have your hosting details password etc. or hackers.  In coding or terms of hacking anything is possible even if u set max security level. Its the matter of time required for people to hack into your databases. don't bother so much just make use of what phpmyadmin have provide us with